# class extends AppCompatImageView Supertype initialization is impossible without primary constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

There is a Custom Imageview class that extends AppCompatImageView

It shows error : **Supertype initialization is impossible without primary constructor**

```
class ImageViewVasl : AppCompatImageView() {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        initialize(context = context, attrs = null)
    }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        initialize(context = context, attrs = attrs)
    }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(
        context,
        attrs,
        defStyleAttr
    ) {
        initialize(context = context, attrs = attrs)
    }
    private fun initialize(
        context: Context?,
        attrs: AttributeSet?
    ) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call parent's constructor:

```
class PieChart(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs)
```

In your source code, I cannot see where you call the parent's constructor.
More detail in this link : https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view

Comment: Expecting a 'this' or 'super' constructor call

Comment: I saw in your source code, you have three constructor method. Just one of them should use 'super', two others use 'this'. Read this blog : https://antonioleiva.com/custom-views-android-kotlin/

Comment: Solved : class ImageViewVasl(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : AppCompatImageView(
    context,
    attrs,
    defStyleAttr
){}

Answer (score 1):

try:

```kotlin
class ImageViewVasl() : AppCompatImageView(){
  constructor(context: Context) : this(context) {
        initialize(context = context, attrs = null)
    }
  ...
}
```

or:

```kotlin
class ImageViewVasl: AppCompatImageView{
    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, 0)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a cycle in the delegation calls chain

Answer (score 0):

Just remove **()** after : AppCompatImageView(), like this

```
class ImageViewVasl : AppCompatImageView {
...
...
}
```